# jstree contextmenu - how to save changes

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, jstree

I'm trying to do a very simple thing and seem to have hit a brick wall. It may already be in the docs but I failed to find it.

I'm trying to save a newly created node or a renamed one. I'm starting with a very basic setup:

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'check_callback' : true
    },
    'plugins' : ['contextmenu', 'dnd', 'state']
}).on('create_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
    console.log('saved');
});
```

What I'm expecting is:
1) Right click on one of existing nodes.
2) Click "create" - that's when `console.log('saved');` fires
3) I type in a name of a new node
4) Press "enter" to save the data - at this point I want to run an ajax request to save new node in DB.

How do I catch the event from point 4) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of the plugin suggested to listen for the rename_node event. So the working code is:

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'check_callback' : true
    },
    'plugins' : ['contextmenu', 'dnd', 'state']
}).on('rename_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
    console.log('saved');
});
```

Comment: I'm on the same problem with creating folders and files in the tree that will save in the database with ajax and then refreshes the page on success to show new data from the database in the tree. Is there a tutorial that shows how this ajax call to the server can be done? I would appreciate it if anyone can answer since I am really stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At times if this doesn't work and you wanted to go for create_node event, then use,

```
$('#tree').jstree({
'core' : {
    'check_callback' : true
},
'plugins' : ['contextmenu', 'dnd', 'state']
}).bind('create_node.jstree', function(e, data) {

console.log('saved');

});
```

this might just do the trick. Or if atall if it is being used in some pop-up use the live event instead of on event of jquery, that will surely hit the spot.